# Windows 7 on MacBook Pro w/ External Display

Tags: windows-7, mac, graphics-card, boot-camp, external-display

Windows 7 is not recognizing my external display on my MacBook Pro. It has an NVidia GeForce 9400, but windows is just using it's generic pnp driver. I've tried downloading updates from NVidia, but they are not installing. Has anyone solved this one yet?

Comment: Which MacBook Pro do you have? Mine worked flawlessly (2008, express card-slot), the one of a colleague shows your symptoms (2009, SD card-slot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the right drivers. Windows update should handle if for you, but if you want to try NVidia's latest, you need to know if you will use the [Windows 7 32bit Geforce 9M notebook drivers](http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/195.62/195.62_notebook_winvista_win7_32bit_international_whql.exe) or [Windows 7 64bit Geforce 9M notebook drivers](http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/195.62/195.62_notebook_winvista_win7_64bit_international_whql.exe). These should install fine, if they don't you should tell us what it tells you about why it can't install them.

**Update**. The site now says:

> As part of the NVIDIA Verde Notebook
>   Driver Program, this is a reference
>   driver that can be installed on
>   supported NVIDIA notebook GPUs.
>   However, please note that your
>   notebook original equipment
>   manufacturer (OEM) provides certified
>   drivers for your specific notebook on
>   their website. NVIDIA recommends that
>   you check with your notebook OEM about
>   recommended software updates for your
>   notebook. OEMs may not provide
>   technical support for issues that
>   arise from the use of this driver.

Which reminds me that I found the drivers for the MacBook's display on the Mac OS X Snow Leopard Install/Upgrade DVD. Which was bundled in the boot camp installer for windows.

Answer (score 2):

Please install the Bootcamp drivers - it can be found on the installation discs that came with your Mac, or the OS X installation discs, or you can download it from the web here.

It should resolve all your problems.

To install or repair Boot Camp drivers:

1. Insert the Mac OS X Leopard disc or "Mac OS X Install Disc 1" into your computer.
2. Double-click the setup.exe file if the installer doesn't open automatically.
3. If you are repairing Boot Camp drivers that are already installed, click Repair.
4. Follow the onscreen instructions.

Comment: Bootcamp does not currently support Windows 7.

Comment: Amuck: Since when? I installed the Boot Camp drivers on Windows 7 on my Macbook and everything worked fine, including the graphics adapters

Comment: @Amuck: Bootcamp does not currently *officially* support Windows 7. I was running Win7 betas on Bootcamp on an Aluminum MacBook (last year's model) all spring and summer without issue. And all of the Bootcamp drivers installed and worked smooth as silk.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using a MacBook with BootCamp. I installed the final release of Windows 7. The automatic update for Windows 7 installs the latest Nvidia drivers, and the multiple screen options within Windows 7 works pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the NVIDIA drivers directly also worked for me.  They can be downloaded at: http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook_winvista_win7_186.81_whql.html

Answer (score -2):

Windows 7 is not supported by Bootcamp yet.

Have you tried downloading and installing the drivers from Nvidia directly?

[Latest Nvidia Notebook Drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook_winvista_win7_186.81_whql.html)

Comment: the new BC drivers from 10.6 is Windows 7 ready. or else you can refer to http://techiemusings.typepad.com/techie_musings/2008/10/running-windows-7-pdc-build-on-a-mac-with-boot-camp.html

Comment: The Boot Camp drivers have always worked in Windows 7.